# Lost text messages

Tags: samsung, sms

Today I did a factory reset on my s21 ultra. I have lost all the text messages. I assumed they would restore from Google, but I'm using the samsung text app and the only back up in samsung cloud is from today after the reset. Is there any way to restore these messages as some of them are very important?

Comment: you can ask your contacts if they still have it, export from their phone and import to yours one by one